# Accessing variables with absolute scopes

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I've been investigating the [tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html) for some way to retrieve a variable using absolute name, rather than relative name to the existing scope

Something like `get_variable_absolute` that would receive an absolute path to the var (i.e: `h1/Weights` rather than `Weights` inside a `h1` variable scope)

This question is motivated by extreme frustration with [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37680219/1792701).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer after reading in depth the [tutorial on Sharing Variables](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/variable_scope/index.html#capturing-variable-scope) from TensorFlow.

Suppose:

- you created a variable 'Weights' in a scope 'h1'
- you are in a scope 'foo'
- you want to retrieve the variable 'h1/Weights'

To do that, you need to save the scope object created with `tf.variable_scope('h1')` to use it inside the scope 'foo'.

Some code will be more eloquent:

```py
with tf.variable_scope('h1') as h1_scope:  # we save the scope object in h1_scope
  w = tf.get_variable('Weights', [])

with tf.variable_scope('foo'):
  with tf.variable_scope(h1_scope, reuse=True):  # get h1_scope back
    w2 = tf.get_variable('Weights')

assert w == w2
```

**Conclusion:** When you pass the scope with its python object, and not only its name, you can get out of the current scope.